# Macro to redo previous step if #VALUE! appears

Tags: vba, excel

The following macro code I thought would do the above part but it says that the 3rd line isn't a valid line. I am not quite sure what it would have to be to make it work. It is suppose to refresh the workbook which line 2 does. then look to see if L1 (and N1 if that is possible) brought back a value that is equal to #Value!. If it did then refresh, if not then call TimeStamp.

```
Sub Refresh()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    If Cells("L1").Value = "#Value!" Then
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild
        Else
        Call TimeStamp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells` refers to coordiantes (e.g. `Cells(1,2)` points to cell `A2`). Try using `Range("L1")` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IsError()` to check for the `#VALUE!` error.

```
If IsError(Range("L1")) Then
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    Else
    Call TimeStamp
End If
```

Comment: If I wanted to check N1 as well would I do Range("L1 & N1")?

Comment: You could use `or` in between, so if either `L1` or `N1` returned `#VALUE!` it would refresh. so `If IsError(Range("L1")) or IsError(Range("N1")) Then`

Comment: Perfection. Thank you so much Constuntine